# Is it possible to mod a GameMaker game?

Tags: game-maker, modding

I been google searching on how to mod Game Maker games (Hyper-Light-Drifter to be more specific) but so far everyone says it's impossible to mod the files. The reason I want to do this is I want to learn to program by modding first and seeing examples that is already made, I also really like this game.

If there is a more better place/website to ask this question please tell me.

Comment: With a sufficient amount of effort it's possible to mod just about anything, although that effort might be impractical. Unfortunately this isn't the place to ask these sorts of how-do-I-get-started tasks. For this I'd recommend asking on a GameMaker-specific forum, possibly for the game in question, as modding is often quite specific to the game or technology used.

Comment: Learning to program by modding is kinda one of the hardest ways to learn..